# Rails nested model form is showing random order on child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've followed and used [Ryan Bate's nested model form tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) to create tracks for my releases (in the tutorial it's questions for surveys).

This works really well until I noticed that the order the tracks get added to the DB is seemingly random not as they appear or are entered in the form I need that to be the case.

The tracks are built using the following definition in the release model:

```
 def track_attributes=(track_attributes)
    track_attributes.each do |attributes|
      tracks.build(attributes)
    end
  end
```

Then in the release _form partial I have:

```
<%= f.fields_for :tracks do |builder| %>
<%= render 'track_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

That pulls in the _track_fields partial, containing:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => "text" %>
<%= f.text_field :isrc, :class => "text" %>
<%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
etc
```

Any ideas why the array of tracks is losing the order they were entered?

I am using acts_as_list in the releases_tracks has many through model that works fine, but it takes the order from what's been incorrectly added to the tracks table.

EDIT:

It seems my tracks are being saved with:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true
```

Not via the track_attributes=(track_attributes) def as I had thought.

Does anyone know how to write a before_save method that will sort the tracks by a position field I've now added to the form?

Answer (score 1):

The order in which SQL queries are executed is random in general. This can apply both to a bulk insert and to a select. If you need your records in a certain order, you must use an ORDER BY clause. Depending on how the records are saved, you might be able to sort on the id, otherwise consider adding a field that represents the list position of each item.

Comment: Ah, I thought this might be the case. I'm actually a bit confused about how the tracks are being save now as after commenting out the tracks.build(attributes) line that I thought saved them, I can still save tracks!!

Comment: build does not save the ActiveRecord object; it merely creates it in memory.

Comment: Ah I see. Any idea if I can add a 'sort_tracks' definition and a before_save call to my release model to achieve this?

Comment: Hey Ryan, have you found a way to keep the order of your tracks? I am facing the exact same problem and I can't find a solution. Help!